# Get all the table from a mysql database using prefix and last row value from each table using CI?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

In my database I have so many table with:

> baby_ld_account_

prefix e.g. (baby_ld_account_117179,baby_ld_account_117231).

How can I get all the table with that prefix?
Also get a column value from last row of each table?
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: what code you have tried yet. Please show there.

Comment: I have use the (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'baby_ld_account_%') to get all the table which works fine

Comment: this will results your tables e.g. (baby_ld_account_117179,baby_ld_account_117231).

Comment: Now i have to get a column value from last row of each table for summation

Comment: Get tables in code and use the query to get max id row in the loop, length should be equal to number of tables.